# zsh export path works when directly type in terminal, but not work when put in /.zshrc

Tags: shell, path, zsh, zshrc

I am frustrated on getting this to work... I am using zsh and from a tutorial it needs me to put these three lines in .zshrc in order to get android sdk to work

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android-SDK"
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Android-SDK/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Android-SDK/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

However, after I've done them, zsh always says

```
zsh: command not found: android
```

I've searched around Google and SO and found several posts asking the similar questions, so I've almost tried them all, like removing the double quotes, put $PATH to the front, removing export key word, etc, but none of them works for me. I've restarted iTerm and even my computer.

BUT, once I type them line by line in terminal directly, and then use android, it works!

What is the reason here? Or where should I really put them in for permanent effect?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Try saying `which android` That will give you the path to the android that your system is referring to. Now see if that file is a symlink. If it is a symlink, go and delete the symlink and see if it works? It may be possible that the symlink may be pointing to a location that does not exist.

Comment: Simply editing `.zshrc` doesn't affect the current session. You need to source the edited file to execute the new commands, either manually (`source .zshrc`) or implicitly (by starting a new shell session).

Comment: @Abhinav Thanks for your reply! When I tried that, I got `android not found`. I also found that running these three commands in terminal will persist a permanent effect, so I might just stick to it for now

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your suggestion! I will try that next time when I meet the similar situation. As for now, running them in the terminal directly gives me a permanent effect

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to tell `.zsh` to load the path.

- In your home folder you should see a hidden `.zsh.after` folder
- create a new file called `00-path.zsh`
- open that file and add the following :

`path=(
     $path
     /usr/local/bin:
     /usr/local/sbin:
     /usr/bin:/bin:
     /usr/sbin:
     /sbin:
     /Users/<YOUR_USERNAME>/.yadr/bin:
     /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.yadr/bin/yadr:
     /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/tools:
     /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/:
      /Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/
    )`